# Strange Text After Passing Suggested Edit Audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

Not entirely sure what's happening here but it definitely looks wrong:

[image: weird review text]

The message popped up at the same time as the Congratulations message.

> Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully

It doesn't show up if you load up [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3850630) now so possibly this is no-repro or possibly it only happens when you initially pass a review, or perhaps most likely it's always done it and I'm missing the point entirely. In any case if it is a bug it is certainly minor.

Using Safari 7.0.1 Mac OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The review system suggested something was probably spam, what should I do when I see this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/the-review-system-suggested-something-was-probably-spam-what-should-i-do-when-i)

Comment: @Aditya, certainly strongly related but I'm reporting this as a rendering bug of some sort. It only told me to review carefully after I had already reviewed and it doesn't look like it was supposed to be there at all.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, while that explains the text it doesn't quite address that it was shown only _after_ passing the audit.

Comment: This should be fixed next deploy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a hard to reproduce corner case, but it's not quite a bug. If you weren't aware, we [recently introduced honeypots for anonymous suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216399/the-review-system-suggested-something-was-probably-spam-what-should-i-do-when-i).

The spam notification is completely unaware of audits, and audits are completely unaware of the spam notifications (however, audits do know when something was rejected as spam, that's why it chose the edit as an audit). The actual notification that tells you that the message was identified as spam comes from something completely different.

What happened is, the post was rejected so recently that the origin was still being tracked by the spam filters, which is why you got that message. In effect, this *should* cause anyone to slow down and take a good look (audit or not) before suggesting action.

What's weird here is that you got the message *after* passing the audit, which wasn't very useful. However, as audits should represent the 'real deal' as much as possible, I don't see a reason to not show the extra notification when you happen on something in an audit that originated from something we're tracking as abusive.

Not marking bydesign because the order is backwards, but we probably should show folks that something is being watched by the filters during audits.

Comment: Agreed, extra information is hardly a bad thing even if a little mistimed. Gladly accept it was some weird corner case.

Comment: @OGHaza It's odd, because you _should_ have seen it in the correct order. Marc is having a look now to see if some kind of weird CSS/JS race might be at play.

Comment: @Tim actually, for audits the "should I show this" is entirely random (and quite rare) - it is unrelated to the post being displayed. The problem is timing.

Comment: It's possible that it was shown in the box at the top to begin with and then it repositioned itself down below when the "Congratulations" message replaced it, but I didn't notice what the box originally displayed so I couldn't say.

Comment: Should be fixed next deploy; also, prettier now