# Whats is happening to Audit system today?

Tags: discussion, bug

I came across the below scenario twice today.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: @AlienArrays no duplicate. this is the same audit review twice in a row. and that's kinda broken. This is not about the "possibly spam" notification.

Comment: Related (in terms of why the message is there): [Strange Text After Passing Suggested Edit Audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216787/241771)

Comment: @OGHaza In my case it is coming before Audit result

Comment: Yeah I know, but in that answer he says that part of my issue is just a corner case. I meant the bit: "The spam notification is completely unaware of audits, and audits are completely unaware of the spam notifications", "What happened is, the post was rejected so recently that the origin was still being tracked by the spam filters, which is why you got that message.". Then yesterday they changed the styling. Only related though - it seems either very coincidental or just incorrect that both the question and answer seem to be marked as spam.