# Failed "known good" audit identified post as possible spam

Tags: bug, review-audits, spam-detection

Well this was interesting.  I failed an audit because the community apparently understood the OP's question (which I considered vague), but then I saw this, *after I failed the audit:*

[image]

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/59232

Why are we failing people on posts flagged as spam by the system, claiming that they are good posts? And why are we warning people about the spam identification *after* the audit has already been completed?

Comment: This is interesting. I have often seen the spam message *prior* to selecting an action. I believe the spam message is completely irrelevant, though. I have a feeling it is just used to throw people often regardless of whether or not it actually was flagged as such.

Comment: I swear I saw a meta post like this. Give me a sec to find it. :P

Comment: Does the phrase "our system has identified..." specifically mean the post was not flagged by a user, but by a script? Or could it be either?

Comment: Okay, here it is: [Strange Text After Passing Suggested Edit Audit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216784/strange-text-after-passing-suggested-edit-audit). Not exactly a dupe, as that one was [meta-tag:status-completed]... seems to have un-completed itself.

Comment: Are you now suspended for reviewing?

Comment: -1 for not enough unicorns and waffles.  Never mind the hand drawn circle.

Comment: Wasn't the audit failure for voting to close an open question with a certain number of upvotes? That's what the message seems to indicate. It may be a bad audit case, but the spam warning seems orthogonal to the failed audit. To my knowledge, the warnings are just suggestions that the system spam heuristics were tripped for some reason by the post and that closer examination is needed.

Comment: ["The spam notification is completely unaware of audits, and audits are completely unaware of the spam notifications"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216784/strange-text-after-passing-suggested-edit-audit/216787#216787)

Comment: @BradLarson: Sure, but I think the folks over at UX would agree with me that goofy is goofy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Agreed, showing the "possible spam" warning for a completed review seems a little odd.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be more careful when reviewing, as you may be banned if you fail too many audits. Don't blindly review posts just for a badge - that ruins the system. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/) for more information about review audits. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Corroborating evidence:

I passed my audit: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/59209
but it had a crazy spam marker as well.

[image]

Comment: Important difference though: your audit was on a closed/deleted post, while the asker's audit was on an open/acceptable post. Both were identified as possible spam, though.

Comment: That being said, your audit doesn't look like spam to me (unless I'm missing more in the post from the screenshot). Maybe the "possible spam" flag is acting wonky?

Comment: @ChrisForrence - yes.  And while I didn't include the entire post since it was too long, there was nothing spammy about it.  Needed to be deleted, yes, but not spam.